# C++ template without subtype

Tags: c++, templates

I have something like

```
template<typename T, typename U = SOMETHING<T>> class A;
```

and

```
template<typename T> using B = A<T, SOMETHING_ELSE<T>>;
```

How can I determine whether `SOMETHING` or `SOMETHING_ELSE` is used in a function instantiation, eg:

```
class A: {
template<typename V>
create_new(V v); // return an A only depending on SOMETHING or SOMETHING_ELSE,
  // e.G: if A is instantiated with T, SOMETHING<T> the return shall be A<V, SOMETHING<V> >,
  // but if it is SOMETHING_ELSE, the return shall be of type A<V, SOMETHING_ELSE<V> >
}
```

I know template specialization may be used, but is there a "more beautiful" way to not have to write a lot of new spezialisations when adding more `SOMETHINGS`?

Real code:

```
template<typename Type = long, typename Canceling_Type<Type> = fract::canceled<Type>>
class fraction; // there are different canceling types
```

the function needed is a

```
template<typename Other_Type, typename Other_Cancel_Type>
fraction<decltype(Type() + Other_Type()), WHAT_HERE> &operator+(const fraction<Other_Type,Other_Cancel_Type> &
```

the cancel_types only consist of a static function that canceles a fraction (or doesn't) (not-canceled is similar to that example)

```
template<typename Type>
class meng::math::fract::canceled {
public:
  typedef fraction<Type,canceled<Type>> cancel_type;
  static cancel_type &cancel(cancel_type& to_cancel);
};
```

My idea was to create a fraction out of f so that no precision is lost (e.g. types int and long create a fraction of long),
but with a type of cancelation determined by the two fractions (e.G. 
both canceled yields canceled, mixed yields uncanceled, eg. only the behavior of setter functions is altered, but they are the same mathematical concept and can therefore be calculated together)

(English is not my first language therefore I hope to cancel a fraction means to use the smallest possible numerator and denumerator)

Comment: I do not understand the question. `class A` is not compilable. There is no difference between `A<X, SOMETHING_ELSE<X> >` and `B<X>`. I think, question needs to be rephrased, probably with better code and examples.

Comment: I don't understand after aliasing `B` what you mean. Do you want to define `A`, defining a function with return type `A<T>`, finding from type `X`which is `A<T, U>` `T` and `U` ?

Comment: Show real code, and include information about the overall problem you're trying to solve with this code.

Comment: class A is already a template with parameters T and U, so wouldn't your return value be a new instance of A<V,U>?

Comment: @GManNickG I hoped it would be more clear to use the abstract version

Comment: Aside: Are you sure that `operator+`returns anything with `&` at the end?

Comment: Still need more details. What is canceling type? Does it make sense to add fractions with mixed canceling type?

Comment: @Pixelchemist i copied the wrong (+=)operator. slightly edited += not the real +-operator because I didn't finish implementation on it before asking this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get your intetion, you can specialize some kind of trait.

```
namespace detail
{
  template<class T, class U, class CancelT, class CancelU>
  struct cancelor
  {
    using type = fract::uncanceled<std::common_type_t<T, U>>;
  };
  template<class T, class U>
  struct cancelor<T, U, fract::canceled<T>, fract::canceled<U>>
  {
    using type = fract::canceled<std::common_type_t<T, U>>;
  };
  template<class T, class U, class CancelT, class CancelU>
  using cancel_t = typename cancelor<T, U, CancelT, CancelU>::type;
}

template<class T, class CancelT = fract::canceled<T>>
struct X
{
  template<class U, class CancelU>
  X<std::common_type_t<T, U>, detail::cancel_t<T, U, CancelT, CancelU>> 
    operator+(X<U, CancelU> const & v) 
  { 
    using V = std::common_type_t<T, U>;
    using C = detail::cancel_t<T, U, CancelT, CancelU>;
    auto ret = X<V, C>{/*...*/};
    // do stuff with ret
    return ret;
  }
};
```

And then add them:

```
X<int, fract::canceled<int>> ci;
X<int, fract::uncanceled<int>> ui;
X<long, fract::canceled<long>> cl;
X<long, fract::uncanceled<long>> ul;

auto c = ci + cl;
auto u = ui + ul;
auto cu = ci + ul;
auto uc = ui + cl;

std::cout << type_name<decltype(c)>() << "\n";
std::cout << type_name<decltype(u)>() << "\n";
std::cout << type_name<decltype(cu)>() << "\n";
std::cout << type_name<decltype(uc)>() << "\n";
```

where the output is:

```
struct X<long,struct fract::canceled<long>>
struct X<long,struct fract::uncanceled<long>>
struct X<long,struct fract::uncanceled<long>>
struct X<long,struct fract::uncanceled<long>>
```

Comment: is common_type_t C++14-only? Is it correct that common_type_t = common_type::type?

Comment: @Tarirah: Correct. (Which is also what [the first google hit on `common_type_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type) tells you.)